# output of Neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network, modeling

I am using neural network to model my system (tower crane).

I have a 1000  experimental sample data for both input and output,
but the output of neural network is 998 ?

Is it normal like that or is something wrong? Should it be 1000 as the inserted data?

This is the code I used to extract the neural network output:

```
y = net(x,xi,ai);
```

as default GUI of neural network, I did not changed anything.

I have tried to understand this but I can not figure it out.

Please help.

Comment: No that isn't normal. Can you please provide the data you used for training your network?  Also, please provide the code you used to **actually train your network**.

Comment: how can i provide the data here since it is hug one ?

i tried but it is too long and i dont know is it possible to upload file here ?

thank you for your feedback sir

Comment: Code is crucial. When it comes to the data - you may only write the shape of it.